# Why is my controller action not being called upon re-clicking the button?

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller, partial-views, partial

First, some code:

Here is the initial Action that is called when the page is navigated to:

```
public ActionResult ListCodeTypes()
{
    var CodeList = _entities.Master_Codes.ToList();

    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < CodeList.Count; i++)
    {
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { 
            Text = CodeList[i].description, 
            Value = CodeList[i].code_table_name 
        });
    }

    ViewData["items"] = items;
    return View("CodesAdmin");
}
```

Here is the CodesAdmin aspx page/view code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master"
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
CodesAdmin
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <% Html.RenderPartial("subMenu/ParcelSubMenu"); %>
    <h2>CodesAdmin</h2>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("items")%>
    <input type="button" id="btnGetCodes" name="GetCodes" 
        value="Get Codes" class="fg-button ui-state-default appButton"
        onclick="searchClick()"/>
    <div id="CodeAdminPlaceHolder"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function searchClick() {
            var searchText = $("#items").val();
            $.get("/Admin/CodeListing/", 
                { identifier: searchText }, function (data) {  
                    $("#CodeAdminPlaceHolder").html(data); 
                }, "html");
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Now, here is the controller code that is called from the button click:

```
public ActionResult CodeListing(string identifier)
{
    _entities.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins,
        _entities.Address_Type_Codes);

    var CodeList = _entities.Address_Type_Codes.
        Where(p=>p.active == true).ToList();

    return PartialView("ListOfAddrCodes", CodeList);
}
```

The CodeListing action actually handles multiple inputs depending on the "identifier" parameter.

The resulting partial view, rendered in the "CodeAdminPlaceHolder" div is:

```
<div id="Div15"  class="ui-widget-content">
    <table id="CodeListing" class="tablesorter">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>
                    Short Description
                </th>
                <th>
                    Long Description
                </th>
                <th>
                    Active
                </th>
                <th>
                    Tax Year
                </th>
                <th>
                    Note
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%= Html.ActionLink("Deactivate", 
                            "DeactivateAddrCode", new { 
                                id=item.address_type_codes_id 
                             }) %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: item.short_description %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: item.long_description %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: item.active %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: item.tax_year %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%: item.note %>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            <% } %>
        </tbody>

        <tfoot>
            <tr id="pager">
                <td colspan="6">
                    <img src="/Content/TableSorter/Themes/Default/first.png"
                        class="firstPage" alt="First" />
                    <img src="/Content/TableSorter/Themes/Default/prev.png" 
                        class="prevPage" alt="Prev"/>
                    <input type="text" class="pagedisplay"/>
                    <img src="/Content/TableSorter/Themes/Default/next.png" 
                        class="nextPage" alt="Next"/>
                    <img src="/Content/TableSorter/Themes/Default/last.png" 
                        class="lastPage" alt="Last"/>
                    <select class="pagesize">
                        <option selected="selected" value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option  value="20">20</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>
```

If someone clicks the "Deactivate" Link, this action is called:

```
public ActionResult DeactivateAddrCode(int id)
{
    Address_Type_Codes ac1 = _entities.Address_Type_Codes.
        First(c => c.address_type_codes_id == id);

    ac1.active = false;
    _entities.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.ClientWins, 
        _entities.Address_Type_Codes);

    UpdateModel(ac1);

    _entities.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("ListCodeTypes");
}
```

This loads the page back to the beginning with the dropdown box and the button.

The problem is that, when I click the button to load up the address types, it does not call the "CodeListing" controller action.  I verified this by putting a breakpoint in the "CodeListing" code and, sure enough, the code does not get called.  Therefore, when a choice is made in the dropdown list and the button is clicked, it shows invalid data.  If I stop and restart the app in VS, the data lists correctly.

The CodeListing action gets called once only and I guess the cached page is returned.

We're using the entity framework for Data Access but I don't think our problems have anything to do with this.

Comment: To Clarify,

The CodeListing action is called whenever someone chooses a selection that has not already been chosen and clicks the search button.  However, if the user chooses an option that has been previously chosen, the page seems to refresh with cached information and the controller action is not called.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the CodeListing method have to be decorated with an [HttpPost] attribute to receive the POST request created by a submit button? All of my "button responding methods" have it, and I seem to recall that not having that attribute applied will mean the method won't get called.